# Count of points in specific location - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The following functions calculate the count of points within specified segments. The are four evenly space segments that are designated by `ref_X` and `ref_Y`. Each segment has a 90 degree angle. Segment 1 is directly above `ref_X` and `ref_Y` and the following segments go clockwise.

The overall count works fine but I only know the total number of points in each segment. I'm hoping to determine the segment location of each `id`. I'm aiming to pass the segment label back to the original df for each unique `id` so I know which segment each `id` is located in.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],             
    'id' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],                 
    'x' : [-1,1,-5,-4,-4,3,-5,3],
    'y' : [-4,-2,-4,-8,-3,-3,-6,-6],
    'ref_X' : [-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2,-2],
    'ref_Y' : [-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5,-5],   
    'Angle' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],         
    })

def determine_points(x, y, refX, refY, rotation_angle):

    # Determine starting angle of ref point
    section_angle_start = [(i + rotation_angle - 45) for i in [0, 90, 180, 270, 360]]

    # Set angle of each segment
    Angle = np.arctan2(x-refX, y-refY) * 180 / np.pi
    Angle = Angle % 360

    # adjust range
    if Angle > section_angle_start[-1]:
        Angle -= 360
    
    elif Angle < section_angle_start[0]:
        Angle += 360

    for i in range(4):
        if section_angle_start[i] < Angle < section_angle_start[i+1]:
            break
    else:
        i = 0

    return i+1  

def segmentCount(group): 

    points = []

    # Iterate row count of points per group (time)
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        segment = determine_points(row.x, row.y, row.ref_X, row.ref_Y, row.Angle)
    
        points.append(segment)

    seriesCount = pd.Series([points.count(i) for i in [1,2,3,4]], index = ['Top','Right','Below','Left'])

    return seriesCount

# Count of id's within each segment
countCongestion = df.groupby('Time').apply(segmentCount)
```

output:

```
      Top  Right  Below  Left
Time                         
1       2      0      1     1
2       1      2      0     1
```

intended output:

```
   Time id  x  y  ref_X  ref_Y  Angle Segment
0     1  A -1 -4     -2     -5      0     Top
1     1  B  1 -2     -2     -5      0     Top
2     1  C -5 -4     -2     -5      0    Left
3     1  D -4 -8     -2     -5      0   Below
4     2  A -4 -3     -2     -5      0     Top
5     2  B  3 -3     -2     -5      0   Right
6     2  C -5 -6     -2     -5      0    Left
7     2  D  3 -6     -2     -5      0   Right
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) your `determine_points()` function by rows. The function returns a numeric segment location, so map them with a `label` dictionary:

```py
label = {1: 'Top', 2: 'Right', 3: 'Below', 4: 'Left'}
df['Segment'] = df.apply(lambda row: label[determine_points(*row.iloc[2:7])], axis=1)

#    Time id  x  y  ref_X  ref_Y  Angle Segment
# 0     1  A -1 -4     -2     -5      0     Top
# 1     1  B  1 -2     -2     -5      0     Top
# 2     1  C -5 -4     -2     -5      0    Left
# 3     1  D -4 -8     -2     -5      0   Below
# 4     2  A -4 -3     -2     -5      0     Top
# 5     2  B  3 -3     -2     -5      0   Right
# 6     2  C -5 -6     -2     -5      0    Left
# 7     2  D  3 -6     -2     -5      0   Right
```

Answer (score 1):

Only you have to change your `segmentCount` function and set the segment name as well. Also changed **i** instead of **i + 1** in `determine_points` return value.

```
def determine_points(x, y, refX, refY, rotation_angle):
    # Determine starting angle of ref point
    section_angle_start = [(i + rotation_angle - 45) for i in [0, 90, 180, 270, 360]]

    # Set angle of each segment
    Angle = np.arctan2(x - refX, y - refY) * 180 / np.pi
    Angle = Angle % 360

    # adjust range
    if Angle > section_angle_start[-1]:
        Angle -= 360

    elif Angle < section_angle_start[0]:
        Angle += 360

    for i in range(4):
        if section_angle_start[i] < Angle < section_angle_start[i + 1]:
            break
    else:
        i = 0

    return i #removed + 1


// set segment name
segment_name = ['Top', 'Right', 'Below', 'Left']


def segmentCount():
    segment = []

    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        segmentIndex = determine_points(row.x, row.y, row.ref_X, row.ref_Y, row.Angle)
        segment.append(segment_name[segmentIndex])

    df['Segment'] = segment
    return df
```

**Output:**

```
   Time id  x  y  ref_X  ref_Y  Angle Segment
0     1  A -1 -4     -2     -5      0     Top
1     1  B  1 -2     -2     -5      0     Top
2     1  C -5 -4     -2     -5      0    Left
3     1  D -4 -8     -2     -5      0   Below
4     2  A -4 -3     -2     -5      0     Top
5     2  B  3 -3     -2     -5      0   Right
6     2  C -5 -6     -2     -5      0    Left
7     2  D  3 -6     -2     -5      0   Right
```